# Forward chaining algorithms

Tags: lo.logic

I am interested in learning about the current state of the art regarding forward chaining production systems. I understand that things haven't changed much (regarding the basic algorithms) since 1995's thesis by Robert Doorenbos, available here:

http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/1995/CMU-CS-95-113.pdf

Am I right, or is there some other work I should be aware of?

Comment: Have you browsed the papers that cite the thesis you linked to? What did you find?

Comment: I've mostly found heuristic improvements, modifications to change semantics, and extensions of different kinds to RETE, but it does not seem to me that there's been any progress beyond RETE.